# System.InvalidOperationException unable to resolve service for type

Tags: asp.net-web-api, automapper

System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'HungerZone.Services.ProductAPI.Models.DTO.ResponseDto' while attempting to activate 'HungerZone.Services.ProductAPI.Controllers.ProductAPIController'.
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
at lambda_method3(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )

I am getting this error

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue, you should register the ResponseDto as a service in the ConfigureServices method of your Startup.cs file. You can use the AddScoped or AddSingleton method depending on your specific use case.

**strong text**
services.AddScoped();

```
// Register AutoMapper and add your mapping profile(s)
services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
enter code here
By adding services.AddScoped<ResponseDto>() in the ConfigureServices method, you make sure that an instance of ResponseDto is available for dependency injection when needed.
```

After making this change, the ProductAPIController should be able to resolve the ResponseDto dependency during its activation.

Please note that if ResponseDto has dependencies of its own, you should make sure to register those dependencies as well in the dependency injection container. Otherwise, you may encounter similar issues with other classes that depend on it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).